# Strided reshaping of a torch tensor

Tags: reshape, tensor, torch

I'm looking for a simple way to reshape a torch tensor x of size (2,8) to a tensor y of size (4,4) so that patches of size (1,4) from x become patches of size (2,2) in y. Here's is the example of what x and y should look like:

x: 
[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
[ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]


y: 
[[ 0.,  1.,  4.,  5.], 
[ 2.,  3.,  6.,  7.],
[ 8.,  9., 12., 13.],
[10., 11., 14., 15.]])

I've tried looking into existing torch functions but haven't found any suitable one yet. Is there a simple way to perform this kind of reshaping of a tensor?

Answer (score 1):

Using the amazing `einops` library ([github repo](https://github.com/arogozhnikov/einops)):

```py
from einops import rearrange
y = rearrange(x, 'b (h1 h2 w) -> (b h2) (h1 w)', h1=2, h2=2)
```

That's it!

It only uses native torch operations as long as `x` is a torch tensor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly and very elegant, just what I needed.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer ;)